English translation of Borel-Serre's "Théorèmes de finitude en cohomologie galoisienne"?
Is there an English translation of this text, or at least some English language paper that proves the same results?
I especially need a proof of the following fact which is in this paper: Say $k$ is a locally compact Hausdorff field, $G$ an algebraic group defined over $k$, $V$ a variety over $k$ and suppose $G$ acts regularly on $V$. Then the natural map $G/\mathrm{Stab}_G(x) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Orb}_G(x)$ is a homeomorphism in the locally compact topology.

Some of resuts of this paper are reproduced in Serre's book "Cohomologie galoisienne", which has been translated into English: J.-P. Serre, Galois Cohomolgy, Springer, Berlin, 1997.

Concerning your question: this probably follows from the definition of the topology in the quotient set $G/{\rm Stab}_G(x)$.

@MikhailBorovoi can you elaborate?

Send me the page number where this is proved in "Th'eor`emes de finitude ...".

@MikhailBorovoi I haven't got that far yet. I am just reading it in French using ChatGPT at this point
